# how to clear the cache data when using ajax?

Tags: ajax

I am using Ajax to retrieve the data from server as below based on some ID to perform auto suggest function. however when i submit the form and update the database, the auto suggest field suppose should not contain anything for this ID anymore, but it will still retrieve data from its cache. do anyone know how to clear the cache and make the Ajax sending request to get the latest data from server every time i press the button? Pls help i really stuck on this whole weeks and couldnt find the solution.

For example: when ID field is 00001, auto suggest field will be 1,2,3. After i submit the form and update the database, when i search for 00001 again, it should not contain anything but it does, it still cache the data as 1,2,3 in suggest field...

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
var data=xmlhttp.responseText;
alert(data);

}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Are you having this problem with all browsers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem once before. This is probably something you can fix in your server settings. What the server does is get a server request, build the answer, and when the same request is done again it sends the same response it built before.

To easily avoid this problem, I added an extra request parameter (a UID).
so:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str+**"?something"=RANDOMGUID**,true);
```

this way you always ha a unique request.

Comment: @Naelv is `RANDOMGUID` a variable like such: `var x = Math.random()`? i'm having this problem right now. it happens when i press the back button on the browser, for whatever reason the old `responseText` doesn't go away

Answer (score 5):

Works with IE8

```
xmlHttp.open("GET", URL, true);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use http headers to prevent the response from being cached:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 24 Oct 2005 16:13:22 GMT
```

Another option is to add another parameter to the url that varies everytime (for example the current time in millis), that way for the browser you ask another url and the cache won't be used.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do is use jQuery#ajax and disable caching.

jQuery will suffix a parameter `?somenumber` to your ajax call which just is sufficient to persuade the browser it cannot use cached data.

I came across this once. Here's the answer I got: [Why does jQuery.ajax() add a parameter to the url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749560/why-does-jquery-ajax-add-a-parameter-to-the-url) .

---

You could do the same thing manually too, but you would have to check if the addition of the parameter is all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

No code provided but some guidance that can help you manage account state consistently across many potential tabs, history, devices, etc:

First, the more condensed version in one long paragraph:

If you want a consistent view for an account, regardless of history back/forward buttons, extra tabs or extra windows (even with different IPs/devices), you can use an increment counter and a heartbeat (heartbeat can be implemented as an XMLHttpRequest send() during a setInterval call configured to say 2 seconds). The increment is managed at the server. The client provides the counter value on each call to server. On each request, the server checks the counter value provided by the client with its own saved value. The server produces the next counter value, persists it, and returns that counter value in the reply so client can use it on its next call. If the client provided the expected counter value, it was a "good" request. If the value provided was different than what the server had stored, the client's call was a "bad" request. Honor good requests. Server may only partly honor bad requests. The client's "next" call could be the next heartbeat or any other request on that account. Multiple client views into that account can overlap but essentially one client only would get the next good call. All other clients would get bad next calls because their counter values will no longer match what the server has stored. If you use one account view, every call to server should be a good call once the session is initiated. [A session can last when browser javascript maintains the counter value, but unless you use cookies or the like, you cannot extend a session if the page is refreshed since javascript would be reinitialized. This means every first call to page would be a "bad" call.] If you use history back, some other tab, or some other device, you should be able to use it, but you will get a bad call at a minimum whenever you switch from one to the other. To limit these bad call cases, turn off heartbeat when that browser view is inactive. Note, don't even implement a heartbeat if you don't mind showing the user a possibly stale page for a prolonged time or if the particular page is unlikely to be stale (but this question assumes you can get stale data on user's browser view).

Let's add more detail:

Every request to a server from an existing opened browser page provides the counter value. This can be, for example, during a form submit or during javascript XMLHttpRequest object .send().

Requests typed from url bar by the user may not have a counter value sent. This and logon can just be treated as having an incorrect count value. These would be examples of "bad" calls, and should be handled as gracefully as possible but should generally not be allowed to update the account if you want a consistent view.

Every request seeking to modify the account (a "writer") must have provided the anticipated counter value (which can be updated at the server other than as +1 if you have more elaborate needs but must be anticipated/unique for a next request). At the server end, if the counter value is the expected one, then process the request variables normally and allow write access. Then include in the reply to client the next legit value the server will expect for that variable (eg, cnt++) and persist that value on the server end (eg, update counter value in database or in some other server file) so that the server will know the next legit counter value to expect whenever the next request comes in for that account.

A request that is a simple "read" is processed the same way as a write request except that if it is a bad request (if the counter doesn't match), a read is more likely to be able to be safely processed.

All requests that provide a different counter value than expected ("bad" requests) still result in the updating of the counter at the server and still result in the client's reply getting the good next expected counter value; however, those bad requests should be ignored to the extent they ask to update the account. Bad requests could even result in more drastic action (such as logging user out).

Client javascript will update the value of counter upon every server reply to what the server returns so that this updated counter value is sent back on any next call (eg, on heartbeat or any talk to server). Every client request will always get a legit next value sent back but only the client that uses that first will be treated as ok by server.

The other clients (ie, any client request that doesn't provide the expected counter value) will instead be given a safe state, eg, the current state as per the database while ignoring any write/update requests. The server can treat the "bad" client calls in other more drastic ways, eg, by logging the user out or whatever, but primarily just make sure to honor at most the bad client's safe read requests, not updating the account in any way.

The heartbeat is necessary only if you want a clean view in short order. To make it light on server, you can have the heartbeat be a simple ping (sending the counter value along). If acknowledged as the good client, you can be done for that heartbeat. If you were a bad client however, then server can return say good fresh info which can be used by javascript in heartbeat code to update the GUI. The heartbeat can be to a different php server page or main one but if different make sure that page gets consistent view of server saved counter variable (eg, use a database).

Another feature you may want to implement for an account is "active/inactive status. The client would be inactive if the mouse position has not changed for a number of seconds or minutes (and no keys typed or other user input during that time). The heartbeat can deactivate itself (clearInterval) when client is inactive. On every user input check if heartbeat is stopped and if so restart it. Heartbeat restart also means user is changing from inactive to active. Stopping the heartbeat would conserve client/server resources when user is browsing on other tab or afk. When becoming active again, you can do things like log out user if they were inactive for a long time, etc... or just do nothing new except restart heartbeat. [Remember, the reply to a heartbeat could indicate the heartbeat request was "bad".. which might possibly be a "drastic" reason to log user out as mentioned above.]

Comment: This "solution" addresses the comment made by user2230470 which is not quite the main question asked but is related in that the randomization trick does not solve the problem at least on some browsers some of the time when you have to deal with refreshes (a refresh would send the same number again and not a new random number). This solution goes further (esp with heartbeat) allowing the user to get a clean updated view almost all the time no matter if looking at old page or multiple open windows or devices.

Answer (score 0):

I know that an answer has been accepted, but it didn't worked in my case. I already had no-cache header added. In my case this was the solution that really worked, because if you add a code after the request, it might not get executed in time for the second piece of code to run successfully:

```
x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        //execute the other code or function only when the page is really loaded!
    }
};
x.open("GET", "add your url here", true);
x.send();
```