# Backbone Model Fetch() is adding extra parameters to url

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I've been going at this for a solid hour, and I have a feeling it might be something simple. I'm doing a basic model fetch with backbone.js with the code below.

```
    var Document = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: "/Package/Documents/GetDocumentById/"

    });

    mydocument = new Document({id: "3978204"});

    mydocument.fetch()
```

I would expect the above code to make a call to the following url

```
localhost:3000/Package/Documents/GetDocumentById/3978204
```

But instead it is adding an extra parameter to the query which is blowing up my method.

```
localhost:3000/Package/Documents/GetDocumentById/3978204?_=1318548585841
```

I have no idea how `?_=1318548585841` get rid of the extra parameter.

Any help would be apperciated.

Comment: Looks like a cache-buster, but AFAIK Backbone doesn't add anything like this by default. Are you using any add-on libraries or anything like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749560/why-does-jquery-ajax-add-a-parameter-to-the-url). This is a cache-buster added by `jQuery.ajax()`, which Backbone uses in the background.

I believe you can remove this by passing `cache:true` as an option to `fetch()` (which gets passed to `$.ajax()`):

```
mydocument.fetch({ cache: true });
```

If that works but you don't want to do it every time, you could set it globally with [jQuery.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/).