# ajax have some string after url like http://localhost:1964/a/b?_=1830

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i don't know why the url will change like /a/b?_=1830 , and return 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
$.ajax({
        url:'/a/b',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (respone) 
        {
           alert(respone);
        },
        error:function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown)
        {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could be a duplicate of this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749560/why-does-jquery-ajax-add-a-parameter-to-the-url, which could mean the URL isn't necessarily the problem. The 500 could be something else.

Answer (score 0):

You will get an idea of actual error inside jqXHR.reponseText
So better put an alert for  **jqXHR.reponseText** in the error block